# Authentication failure! invalid_credentials with google

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-oauth, omniauth, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to get google authentication working on my elasticbeanstalk deployment but I just can't seem to get past the following error when attempting to login:

> (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
>   Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=XXXX" for 204.83.99.130 at 2014-11-15 05:23:41 +0000
>   (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
>   (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, {
>     "access_token" : "XXXX",
>     "token_type" : "Bearer",
>     "expires_in" : XXXX,
>     "id_token" : "XXXX"
>   }

I followed http://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails tutorial and the code I'm deploying works fine on my local machine, but I get the above error on my elasticbeanstalk deployment when attempting to login. What step am I missing here?

Save me people of stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Let me know if I need to add anymore details. Going to bed now. Maybe some sleep will make this issue seem more clear.

Comment: To add some additional detail to this: I set up my rails app on heroku and I can sign in with google so it is definitely an AWS related issue.